# Reading the same file using multiple file streams for multithread applications

Tags: c, fopen, fseek

**Context of the Problem:**
I have a large binary file containing data with a unique structure. A unit of this data is called an "event". Each event has 32016 bytes and a single file includes about 400000 events making the file ~12 GBs. I'm writing a program to process the events and trying to use a multithread approach with several threads reading different segments of the file(having each tread use its own file stream).

The problem is fseek fails to seek to the correct position of the file. the following is the minimal reproducible example. The program reads a binary file with 473797 events with planning to use 20 treads while each tread uses a different file stream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

        FILE *segment[20];
        int ret=0;
        int eventsPerThread=473797/20;
        int eventSize=8004;
        for(int k=0;k<20;++k){
                segment[k]=fopen("Datafile_367.bin","rb");
                if(segment[k]==NULL){
                        std::cout<<"file stream is NULL!"<<k<<"\n";

                }

                ret=fseek(segment[k],eventsPerThread*eventSize*4*k,SEEK_SET);
                std::cout<<ret<<":::"<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";


        }
                return 0;
}
```

The following is the output. fseek is successful sometimes and returns 0 while failing at other times with the error code 22(Invalid argument).

```
0:::Success
0:::Success
0:::Success
-1:::Invalid argument
-1:::Invalid argument
-1:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
-1:::Invalid argument
-1:::Invalid argument
-1:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
-1:::Invalid argument
-1:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
0:::Invalid argument
```

Any explanations for this behavior of the fseek() function?

(Note that the minimal reproducible example is a single tread. multithreading will happen once the program starts to read the events)

Comment: I would recommend changing your approach.  Read all the events in one thread and then dispatch them to worker threads.  Reading the data from disk is going to be I/O bound; storage devices handle sequential access far better than random access.  So it will actually probably be faster to read the file in one thread than to read it concurrently in 20 threads.

Comment: Use `mmap` to map the file and have a single mapping that all threads use

Comment: @erik258 Due to the size of the files that approach doesn't suit this application.  I'm more constrained by the processing of events rather than the reading of data, specially because the data files are stored in RAIDed SSD drives. The time to read a single event from the disk is negligible compared to the time that takes to process that event.

Comment: @erik258 is right. You can not speed up reading, but you can use more CPUs to speed up processing. What you are saying is the exact thing erik is saying. A single thread reading events maximizes I/O, and then every event is offloaded to a pool of threads. This fits perfectly your application.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I'm aware of what he said. I know I can't speed up reading, I don't want to speed up reading and I don't care about the reading speed. Reading is far more faster than processing.  This is not a small file, I can't just read all of the events and store them in memory just to be accessed by the worker threads. I don't want to implement complex thread locks and potentially compromise real processing power. Is one reading tread faster than several treads? possibly, barely. Is it beneficial for the final output of this application? No.

Comment: @danulagodagama what's the exact size of the Datafile_367.bin file? We need that for a [mcve].

Comment: @Jabberwocky the file size is 15,168,540,480 bytes.

Comment: @Jabberwocky This can be calculated: 473797 * 32016 = 15169084752. (danula, why do you have another result?)

Comment: @danulagodagama Does your file size differ from the theoretical value because 473797 does not divide by 20 without remainder? The difference seems to be 17 * 32016...

Comment: @thebusybee I know it can be calculated, but I wanted to know the _actual_ size, not the site it should be. Anyway, the issue was different as you pointed out in your answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Uh, I see, I understood you request wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is the overflow in your offset calculation. You use `int`, which is apparently 4 bytes wide. `INT_MAX` is 2147483647 for this width.

Let's see:

| k | `eventsPerThread * eventSize * 4 * k` | overflowed `int` | return value of `fseek()` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 758427024 | 758427024 | 0 |
| 2 | 1516854048 | 1516854048 | 0 |
| 3 | 2275281072 | -2019686224 | -1 |
| 4 | 3033708096 | -1261259200 | -1 |
| 5 | 3792135120 | -502832176 | -1 |
| 6 | 4550562144 | 255594848 | 0 |
| 7 | 5308989168 | 1014021872 | 0 |
| : | : | : | : |

The resulting `int` becomes negative because of the overflow, and `fseek()` is not happy with that.

First, make sure your `long`s are more than 4 bytes wide. Then change at least one operand of your multiplication to `long`. For example like this `eventsPerThread * eventSize * 4L * k`.

*Final note: Consider to use more spaces to make your code more readable.*

Comment: If the code relies on longs being more than 4 bytes wide it would be a good idea to build that assumption into the code itself. E.g.: `_Static_assert(sizeof(long)>4, "Long is not so long");`.